# Decode buffer received from a device, via USB

Tags: javascript, node.js, serial-port, buffer

I'd like to convert the buffer to a string, I've tried many things but I can't achieve it. Any ideas?

is the data sent from a device to a printer. I capture that data with serialPort in nodejs and I need to convert it...

Thank you!

```js
console.log(JSON.stringify(data));

//return:

{"type":"Buffer","data":[132,132,0,1,4,128,0,1,3,67,132,132,132,132]}
{"type":"Buffer","data":[33,3,192,100,226,160,164,134,135,133,165,133,134,67,164]}
{"type":"Buffer","data":[135,228,133,132,132,132,229,197,135,102,98,34,32,2,4]}
{"type":"Buffer","data":[128,1,66,33,32,98,131,164,135,228,133,67,1,65,128]}
{"type":"Buffer","data":[0,4,97,66,2,36,64,132,229,132,167,100,98,64,32]}
{"type":"Buffer","data":[131,0,4,32,224,132,132,164,100,2,97,39,98,67,64]}
{"type":"Buffer","data":[36,32,34,67,98,224,164,133,164,197,196,67,132,131]}
{"type":"Buffer","data":[164,135,100,101,98,66,64,135,229,132,163,67,66,227,164]}
{"type":"Buffer","data":[135,100,101,2,34,135,228,132,163,67,32,227,132,135,100]}
{"type":"Buffer","data":[101,2,32,225,32,224,135,229,100,67,3,32,103,34,99]}
{"type":"Buffer","data":[99,67,67,67,67,240]}
```

```js
console.log(data.toString("utf-8"));

//return:

�
� ╔╝� ╔╚C����!
╚�d⠤������C��
䅄��兇fb" ╗╝�
╔B! b����╔A�
╝aB╗$@�儧db@
� ╝ Ą�e╗a'bC@
$ "Cbअ��C���
�debB@�䅣CBㄧ
de╗"�䄣C ㄇde
╗ ���╚ g"c
cCCCC
```

Comment: You have to implement the protocol that the device uses to talk with the printer.
You cant just "decode" random binary/buffer data to a string.

Answer (score 0):

had 9600 baudrate configured and the device is 19200. That was the mistake... :/